# Need to validate Textbox to enter certain condition using Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

Need to validate textbox using javascript as below condition :

1. Length of the letter should be atleast 6
2. First Letter should be Capital
3. Atleast One Numeric value should be there
4. Atleast one special character should be there

How to do that?

Comment: ... probably regular expressions. Consider adding the `regex` tag to your question.

Comment: BTW, if I may ask a question here: Is there a web-site that creates regular expression literals based on such input parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Form validation:

- http://www.webcheatsheet.com/javascript/form_validation.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_form_validation.asp

JavaScript regular expressions:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Java Script condition for text field validation for name

var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,75}$/;

text field validation for Number

var ck_number=/^[0-9]{1,10}$/;